# Delay in automation Jquery slider

Tags: jquery, automation, slider, delay

I have done a lot of research on this and cannot find anything on this topic or how to do it.

I have added automation to my jquery slider however, i need to delay it... Can anyone please help me, here is my Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kenton9008/836pW/

```
    function auto() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 1500, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
    });
    auto(function(){
        setTimeout(auto, 2000);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `setTimeout` into the callback of the `animate` function should make it work the way you want:

```
function auto() {
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 1500, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        setTimeout(auto, 2000);
    });
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/YL7v8/

Comment: One more question however, how do I make it stop when you hover over the entire slideshow? so that I can use the normal navigation too?

Comment: @user3770518 A quick thought is to [clear the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout) on [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), and resume it (if that's what you want to do) when the mouse leaves the element.

Answer (score 0):

Your Timeout is a bit messed up I think. Instead of calling it from within calling the auto function, just set it to run in the complete function of the animate. Like so:

```
function auto() { 
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 1500, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        setTimeout(auto, 2000);
    });
};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/836pW/3/

Or try using jQuery's `.delay()` function instead like this:

```
function auto() {
    $('#slider ul').delay(2000).animate({
        left: - slideWidth
    }, 1500, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        auto();
    }); 
};
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/836pW/1/